# Error while running subprocess to run yolov5 detect.py file

Tags: python, pickle, yolo

I need to run detect.py file to detect objects from images in a folder from a python script.
When I try running the script I keep getting this pickle invalid load error.

```
import os
import subprocess


img_fdr="./img"
weights_fdr="/runs/train/exp7/weights/best.pt"

subprocess.run(["python3","detect.py","--weights",weights_fdr,"--source",img_fdr])
```

I tried several ways of passing the arguments , still I keep getting the same error.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YqPA.jpg)

Comment: One Tip next time copy the error you get into your question so it can be easily accessed and read without the need for opening a new tab

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
subprocess.run(["python3","detect.py","--weights",weights_fdr,"--source",img_fdr])
```

should look like this:

```
subprocess.run(f"python3 detect.py --weights {weights_fdr} --source {img_fdr}")
```